# How to integrate a funtion over a tensor of [i][j]th elements

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, integral

I want to integrate a function and create a matrix of integrals, wherein for each element, only the number of [i][j] changes in Python.
The following equation is the same problem writing in Mathcad:

[image]

I've tried the following program, which runs completely fine, but the results are false:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

# Define the dimensions of the tensor
NMHT_0 = 12

# Create the tensor
I00 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))

# Define the integrand function
def integrand(x, m, n):
    return (np.sin((n - 2) * (np.pi) * x)) * (np.sin((m - 2) * (np.pi) * x))

# Perform the integration
for m in range(1, NMHT_0 ):
    for n in range(1, NMHT_0 ):
        result, error = spi.quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(m, n))
        I00[m, n] = result

# Display the results
for row in I00:
    print(' '.join(f'{val:.3f}' for val in row))
```

Any ideas
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the results are false"? Are you saying that the integral values are incorrect?

Comment: From what I can see, the integral results are correct. One recommendation: use [`scipy.integrate.quad_vec`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html) instead of `quad`. Then you won't need a nested `for` loop.

Comment: Do you still think that the integral result is wrong? You need to remember that the sine function is orthogonal to off-frequency versions of itself. So, the integral of sin(m*x)*sin(n*x) is 0 unless m = n.

Comment: And if you cannot figure out how to use `quad_vec` for this problem, you can post a question about it. But make sure you actually give it a try first and search for other stack overflow questions about it.